# tengo numeros enteros pero quiero mostrarlos por columnas

Tags: php

ejemplo  $numero = 1234;
y quiero mostrarlo asi como la imagen;
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código que has intentado

Comment: Puedes usar [`str_split`](https://www.php.net/str_split) para crear un array de dígitos e imprimirlos como desees. Algo así: `$mArray=str_split($numero); foreach ($mArray as $n) {echo $n;}` Dentro del for puedes poner más cosas, como `<td>` si quieres crear una tabla. Haz tu intento y si tienes algún problema nos dices. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

**Aqui esta codigo para resolver el problema**

Se usa como se comento A. Cedano el comando str_split() para convertir el string en array, luego se hace un recorrido del array con el for () para colocar en cada item la etiqueta `<td>`

```
<?php
$numero = 1234; 
// convierte el string en un array
$arr1 = str_split($numero);
?>
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <?php
                // ciclo para reccorrer el array y construir 
                // un <td></td> por cada item
                for ($i=0; $i < count($arr1); $i++) { 
                    echo '<td>'. $arr1[$i]  . '</td>';
                   }                
            ?>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Espero que pueda ayudarte...